# Skip every nth result row in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for a way to skip rows in PostgreSQL.

Two ways I could do this are using:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id % 5 = 0
```

However I'd have to fetch sequential rows to properly skip. For instance if I fetch row (with ids) 0,3,5,
 it would not skip 4 out of 5 rows, but instead result in (ids) 0 and 5.

Or skip outside of SQL:

```
$count = 0;
while($row = progres_fetch_row($result))
  if ($count++ % 5 == 0)
     // do something
```

What is the fastest way to get every nth row from a SQL database?

Comment: ProgreSQL, as given in the first sentence, but I'm also curious for MySQL.

Comment: You mean PostgreSQL, or is it a separate RDBMS I'm not aware of?

Comment: it seems the typo in comments but very first line in OP says "I'm looking for a way to skip rows in (Prostgre)SQL" so it is PostgreSQL. though he is also interested in MySQL solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. I can't change the comment anymore though. It is PostgreSQL which I'm most interested in.

Comment: `What is the fastest way to get every nth row from a SQL database?` Probably using windowed functions, but the most efficient implementation will of course heavily depend on the exact structure of the table(s) in question.

Comment: "However I'd have to fetch sequential rows to properly skip. For instance if I fetch row (with ids) 0,3,5, it would not skip 4 out of 5 rows, but instead result in (ids) 0 and 5." i didn't get this. can you elaborate this what are the base rows, what is you will be fetching and how does % operator does not work in your case.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you use PostgreSQL, you can use [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT *, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) AS row
  FROM yourtable
) t
WHERE t.row % 5 = 0
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is (ANSI) standard SQL (except for the modulo operator) and works on a wide range of DBMS - just not with MySQL

Comment: but with just one "=" not two here-

Answer (score 1):

If n is large enough (like 1000), you can consider using [WITH RECURSIVE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) queries like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE foo(name) AS
    (SELECT name FROM people ORDER BY name LIMIT 1)
  UNION
    (SELECT
      (SELECT name FROM people
        WHERE name >= foo.name
        ORDER BY name OFFSET 1500 LIMIT 1)
      FROM foo LIMIT 1
    )
SELECT * FROM foo
```

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong. The closing one after the very first `limit 1` is closing the CTE. So you either have a CTE marked as `recursive` that isn't recursive, or you have an invalid CTE. But even if you get your parentheses right, you'd wind up with "*LIMIT in a recursive query is not implemented*". And even if that _would_ work I doubt that this is more efficient that using a window function (and you wouldn't actually need the nested SELECT in the recursive part to begin with). As it stands your answer is plain wrong (and not working)

Answer (score 0):

@Guillaume Poussel  works fine for skipping nth row, but if we want to remove n elements between 0 to x range, it wont include the 0th row.

So, if we want to only include the every 5th element starting from 0 index, this is the solution:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT *, row_number() OVER() AS row
  FROM dcia.test
) t
WHERE (t.row-1) % 5 = 0
```

Original indexes:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

Indexes after the above statement:

```
0,5,10,15
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a generic and probably quite slow solution in case you don't have access to ranking functions, such as [`row_number()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19595950/521799). So in MySQL, you would write:

```
select * 
from x x1
where (
  select count(*) 
  from x x2 
  where x2.id <= x1.id
) % 5 <> 0
order by x1.id asc
```

If you want to add additional predicates, just be sure to add them to both outer and inner query:

```
select * 
from x x1
where x1.id % 2 = 0
and (
  select count(*) 
  from x x2 
  where x1.id % 2 = 0
  and x2.id <= x1.id
) % 5 <> 0
order by x1.id asc
```

- [SQLFiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e413c/15)
- [SQLFiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e413c/13)

#### Remarks:

- The inner query has to have the same table references and predicaets as the outer query
- The inner query needs to count the number of rows "before" the current row from the outer query. "Before" is defiend by the outer query's `ORDER BY` clause